# Prove that for any integer $x$ and any integer $k$ that $x \equiv_k x$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, solution-verification

My working: 
$$
x \neq x + kq 
$$

I solved for kq and got 
$$
kq \neq 0
$$

Now I'm partially confused because the question had some further detail to it which was :

" Be careful not to assume what you need to prove. Don't start your proof by assuming there's a choice of $q$ where $x = x + kq$. "

After reading that statement I changed my approach. So I decided to negate the theorem and reached to $x≠x+kq$.

I'm not sure if what I did is right, because the last time I did proofs was when I was 16 and now I'm starting to get back into them.

Also if u think it's wrong, please feel free to provide hints. But don't write the answer :) .

Comment: What does $\equiv_k$ means ?

Comment: Is $\equiv_k$ your notation for modulo $k$? In that case, observe $k \mid x-x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating and filling in the way you wanted to prove it using contradiction.

You start by assuming $x \not\equiv_k x$ and then you wrote $x \neq x + kq$.
However, make sure you actually understand what you mean by that. To be more specific, you have introduced a new character $q$ without any introduction as to what it is.

What you really should write is: $x \neq x + kq$  **for any** $q \in \mathbb{Z}$.

In that case, the contradiction becomes clear when you rearrange the equation to write:
$$kq \neq 0 \quad \text{for } \textbf{any }  q \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

Do you now see what the clear contradiction is?
Note: to show that the above is a contradiction, you just need to come up with *one* value of $q \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $kq \neq 0$ is *not* true.

---

However, I would suggest taking the more direct route of proof by showing that $k \mid (x - x)$.

Comment: yes, i understand what you mean now. So pretty much when I make a contradiction, all i have to do is just find 1 number or example where i can prove that the contradiction is wrong.

Comment: @jame_smith, in this particular case, yes. Because your contradiction involves a claim of the form "for every $q$, ..." (this is what you had originally missed). On the other hand, if your contradiction had involved something of the sort "there exists a $q$ such that [something]", then finding one counterexample would *not* have worked. You then would have to show that the [something] is false *for every* $q$.

Comment: Also another question what does the " | " stand for in $k | (x-x)$

Comment: @jame_smith: the notation "$a \mid b$" is used as shorthand for "$a$ divides $b$" or "$b$ is divisible by $a$". The usual definition of that is: $\exists c \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ac = b$. To connect it with your question, we have that $a \equiv_k b$ if and only if $k \mid (b-a )$.

Answer (score 1):

Negation is taking an unneeded detour,
As $x=x+kq$, $0 = kq$.  Since $k \neq 0$, $q = 0$.
Thusforth, $x\equiv x(\mod k)$.
A direct proof.  As $x - x = 0$:
$k | x - x$; $x - x\equiv 0 (\mod k)$;  $x \equiv x(\mod k)$.